# ftplib.error_temp: 421 There are too many connections from your internet address

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I use the ftplib module in Python to download some satellite data, but after I download 1 file, I try to close the connection then it gives this exception:

```
"ftplib.error_temp: 421 Timeout."
```

After 10mins, I try to reconnect the ftp site to download some data again, another exception again:

```
>>> ftp.connect('ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 156, in connect
    self.welcome = self.getresp()
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 243, in getresp
    raise error_temp(resp)
ftplib.error_temp: 421 There are too many connections from your internet address.
```

how can I reconnect to the ftp site again ?

Comment: They probably limit the number of requests that you can make in a time period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 421 There are too many connections from your internet address.

That's a restriction done by the target site to limit the amount of connections done by a single system. It is unknown how exactly this restriction is enforced, i.e. if it just counts the currently active connections or if it takes connections attempts within some time frame. You should retry later.